# Every iteration starts with previous iteration result

Tags: javascript

How do you iterate over an array with every iteration taking the previous result? I am looking for same value in array B like is in array A, but array A has only one value, like result of for in loop. I want return array C which is starting array substracted of all items in array A.

I have this code so far:

```
x = newArray.indexOf(zeme[0]);

for (b = 0; b < newArray.length; b++) {
  if (x === b) {
    newArray.splice(b, zeme.length);
  }
}
```

With values:

```
array B = ['can', 'usa', 'eng'];

array A = ['eng'];
array A = ['can'];
```

Getting results:

```
array C = ['can', 'usa']
//first iteration, found 'eng' and deleted.
array C = ['usa', 'eng']
//second iteration found 'can' and deleted.
```

Required result:

```
array C = ['usa']
//after first iteration in array left only two items ['can', 'usa']
//after second iteration take array ['can', 'usa'] and splice 'can'
```

Comment: [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: I still dont get what you are trying to explain?

Comment: What is `zeme`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

> I want return array C which is starting array substracted of all items in array A.

is the gist of your question, it sounds like you want array intersection.

```
function intersect(a, b) {
    return a.filter((v) => b.indexOf(v) === -1);
}

console.log(intersect(['can', 'usa', 'eng'], ['usa', 'eng']));
```

outputs

```
['can']
```

(Note: the above implementation is not optimized; it can get terribly slow for large `b` arrays, as the worst-case complexity is O(n^2) there.)

Comment: You can get make it O(n) by creating a set out of `b`. `return a.filter((v) => !bSet.has(v));`. Of course, the tradeoff is space for the `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, but this could work if I had all values in one array b and I don't. Have b = ['usa'], b = ['eng'] in two outputs like result of "for in loop" from object keys. I can't push these vaules in one array because it does not work for "if statement" filtering. That mean I get two arrays output with your function as I mentioned in original question section getting results.

Comment: @slider And initialization time for the set, which will probably not be worth it for small `b`s. (A heuristic, say, `b.length > 20`?, would be reasonable.)